# CONVERT FY format to exact date in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, m

I have a string formatted date field which says "FY23Q1", now assuming the fiscal year starts in October and ends in September, I want to recode the string into 10/01/2022. ie the first date of the month

**INPUT Expected output:**
FY23Q1   10/01/2022
FY23Q2   01/01/2023
FY23Q3   04/01/2023

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a new custom column in PQ and paste in the following code. Make sure [Column1] refers to your column with FY23Q1 date in it.

```
let 
year = Number.From(Text.Middle([Column1], 2,2)),
quarter = Number.From(Text.Middle([Column1], 5,6)),
startDate = Date.AddQuarters( #date(year-1+2000, 10, 1), quarter - 1)


in startDate
```

Full working example:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45Wcos0Mg40VIrVgTKNEExjBNMExjQBqY0FAA==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Column1 = _t]),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each let 
year = Number.From(Text.Middle([Column1], 2,2)),
quarter = Number.From(Text.Middle([Column1], 5,6)),
startDate = Date.AddQuarters( #date(year-1+2000, 10, 1), quarter - 1)


in startDate)
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

[image]

Comment: I implemented your code and got the same date for all values 4/1/2022

Comment: Can you paste your full query. It works perfectly on your provided data as well as some extended data I tried it on. I have updated the answer so you can see a full working example.

Comment: despite replacing the "Column1" it is not working, I even replaced the source but no luck

Comment: It definitely works with your test data. You just need to incorporate it properly. Can you paste the full query you have?